# Got NOTTY for the Linux kernel ramfs with unlocked_ioctl

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, ioctl

I want to add a customized file system operation for kernel ramfs by `ioctl` (i.e., `unlocked_ioctl` in `struct file_operations`). What I did is to copy the ramfs code, rename `.name` as "myramfs", add a mount function in `.mount` of `struct file_system_type`. In this way, I could mount "myramfs" on a directory. Then I created an ioctl function for `unlocked_ioctl` and basically this function is now only for testing purpose and doing simple switch...case and printk. I defined two ioctl commands by `_IO`. I am sure that the functionalities of "myramfs" without ioctl work properly.

Here are some code snippets:

**myramfs.c (ramfs module code)**

```
#include "myioctl.h"
// Only for testing purpose
static long myramfs_unlocked_ioctl(struct file *f,
                unsigned int cmd,
                unsigned long arg)
{
    switch (cmd) {
        case IOCTL_NUM1:
            printk(KERN_INFO "Call by IOCTL_NUM1\n");
            break;
        case IOCTL_NUM2:
            printk(KERN_INFO "Call by IOCTL_NUM2\n");
            break;
        default:
            printk(KERN_INFO "Call by Default\n");
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}


const struct file_operations ramfs_file_operations = {
  ...
  .unlocked_ioctl = myramfs_unlocked_ioctl,
};
```

**myioctl.h (self-defined ioctl header file)**

```
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#define IOC_CODE    '1'
#define IOC_NO(x)   (IOC_CODE + (x))
#define MY_IOC(n)   _IO(IOC_CODE, IOC_NO(n))
#define IOCTL_NUM1  MY_IOC(1)
#define IOCTL_NUM2  MY_IOC(2)
```

I wrote a test driver C program in user space to call the ioctl of "myramfs":
**test.c (user-space driver program to call ioctl and hope to get printk info in dmesg)**

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include "myioctl.h"
...
int dirfd;
//mp is the pathname of myramfs mountpoint
dirfd = open(mp, O_RDONLY | __O_DIRECTORY);
if (dirfd < 0) {
    exit(1);
}

int ret;
ret = ioctl(dirfd, VERIFS_CHECKPOINT, (void *)arg); // Got ENOTTY in this statement
```

When I called `ioctl` in user space, I got errno = 25 (ENOTTY) which means inappropriate ioctl for device. I suspect that is because I used mountpoint fd as the first argument of user space `ioctl` instead of the device fd. But ramfs does not need to be backed by a device so I cannot use device fd as ioctl argument. I am not sure where the issue is and if I implemented ioctl for ramfs correctly. Could you please help with this NOTTY error in the user driver program? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You add method `unlocked_ioctl` to structure `ramfs_file_operations`, which, according to its name, is for **regular files** only. But you user space program attempt to work with **directory**.

Comment: Your device has a major and minor number. You need to make a device node and open that to have a file descriptor that maps to your device.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you so much. I tried to create a file in _myramfs_ mountpoint, then get this file's `fd` by `open`, and feed into `ioctl` as argument. It works now, and I can get the expected kernel output. I wonder if I need to create a file before doing `ioctl` in userspace. Can I call `ioctl` for a clean filesystem without any regular file in it?

Comment: @stark Thanks. It looks like ramfs does not require a device while mounting, and I don't know how to map a device for ramfs. Any idea?

Comment: You could add ioctl for directories too. Instead of assignment to `&simple_dir_operations` create your own file operations for directory, and add `unlocked_ioctl` to it.